# hostapd-wpe for Windows 10

Tags: hostapd

I would like to implement `hostapd-wpe` according to this [patch](https://patches.aircrack-ng.org/wpe/hostapd-wpe/), but it looks like Windows 10 uses MD5 certificates, so I changed `default_md` entry from `sha1` to `md5` in the `ca.cnf`, `server.cnf`, and `client.cnf` files.

I then created certs with:

```bash
cd /etc/hostapd-wpe/certs
./bootstrap
make install
```

But when I run `hostapd-wpe /etc/hostapd-wpe/hostapd-wpe.conf`, I get:

```bash
OpenSSL: tls_global_client_cert - Failed to load client certificate
error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak
```

How can I force `openssl` to work with `md5`?

Comment: Where did you find that Windows only uses `md5` hashes?  `md5` is not even remotely a secure hashing algorithm (min `sha256`), especially for WiFi authorization

Comment: I found it here: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/issues/1708

Comment: I would search around a bit more, as that's two years old and the version of Windows 10 at that time was v1709, which was [EoL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) [End of Life] a year ago (April '19).  AFAIK, OpenSSL won't allow the use of `md5`, as it's not a secure hashing algorithm and hasn't been for ~10yrs.  I know Windows 10 supports, at a minimum,  `sha1`, as that's the hashing algorithm used for the Windows users' personal token cert (see `crtmgr.msc` > Personal), and Powershell supports up to `sha512` (`Get-FileHash`)